# nginx, prerender and angular routing issue

Tags: angularjs, nginx, seo, prerender

I am developing a dynamic `angular` website (using `html5mode` to remove the `#`). It uses `Elasticsearch` to grab some data and render the contents. `nginx` is responsible for the mapping to `Elasticsearch` and my website root.

In order to get the whole site SEO-capable, I am trying to integrate [prerender](https://github.com/prerender/prerender), using a local instance (`http://localhost:3000`).

I am desperately trying to do apply the prerender magic in combination with an nginx `location /angular_test`. The default nginx prerender middleware config does not work for `location`s. Find below my nginx configration:

```
upstream elasticsearch {
    zone elasticsearch 64K;
    server localhost:9200;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name angular_test_server;

    location /angular_test {
        rewrite_log on;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log notice;

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        if ($prerender = 1) {
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri?;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        break;
        }

        # support html5mode of angular (fallback to index.html and let angular do the routing)
    try_files $uri $uri/ /angular_test/index.html;
    }

    location /es/ {
        rewrite /es/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
        proxy_redirect http://elasticsearch /es/;
    }

}
```

When I access http://localhost/angular_test/search?_escaped_fragment_= I get a 404 because nginx tries to load the file `/var/html/www/angular_test/search`. This should be covered by angulars routing (see try_files doing a try on the index.html). http://localhost/angular_test?_escaped_fragment_= works just fine

When I use something like the following (as propsed here https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802), it does not even get into the `@prerender` location part.

```
location /angular_test {
    # support html5mode of angular (fallback to index.html and let angular do the routing)
    try_files $uri $uri/ /angular_test/index.html @prerender;
}
```

Is there any way to get this setup running with `prerender`? I have the feeling that I do not use nginx in the right way here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the solutions. [If is really evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) in nginx locations!

It works when the `if(...)` logic is moved out of the `location` and to the `server`. Here is my final configuration:

```
upstream elasticsearch {
    zone elasticsearch 64K;
    server localhost:9200;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name angular_test_server;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    location /angular_test {
        rewrite_log on;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log notice;

        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        if ($prerender = 1) {
            #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
            #set $prerender "$host:3000";
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

        # support html5mode of angular (fallback to index.html and let angular do the routing)
        try_files $uri $uri/ /angular_test/index.html;
    }

    location /es/ {
        rewrite /es/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
        proxy_redirect http://elasticsearch /es/;
    }

}
```